# combine all elements in a slide - group and ungroup

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I have various elements in a slide with shape_type as freeform, Autoshape need to select these and group it as a group object (MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.GROUP) so that its alignment can be altered as a single element and ungroup it. using group_shape. shapes I'm able to access the shapes of a grouped object. but grouping and ungrouping objects is this possible using python_pptx?
This is similar to a grouping and ungrouping of elements we are able to do in MS PowerPoint application